# Incorrect integer value and other mysql errors

Tags: mysql

completed a migration from an older setup to a newer setup.  Is there a way to tell MySQL to ignore these types of errors and simple force the query through if empty then put in 0 etc or something?  the issue I am running into is that to fix the problem would require changing a lot of codebase (That I didn't write) when it's all going to be replaced soon anyway.  In short, I need to get a newer version of MySQL to be "ok" with how the older version of MySQL used prior was.

Comment: You need to share what exactly your trying (sample of the SELECT or INSERT) and what the error is. There is no such thing as 'forcing' a computer language to do something - for each language (and maybe even by version, release) there are rules - if the rules are met, you get output; if not, you get errors. In some limited cases you can ignore warnings; but real errors must be dealt with. Good luck.

Comment: inccorect integer value: for column xyz at row 1: insert into table (`xyz`) values ('');  The issue here being the string is not an integer but still an empty value (so should be considered to be a 0).  old mysql accepted this, new doesn't.